# ¿Cómo combinar dos tablas de MS SQL sin duplicar el ID de la primer tabla?

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando realizar un JOIN en dos tablas donde la primera contiene un folio y la segunda contiene los registros asociados a ese folio. Lo que intento hacer es que al realizar el JOIN no se dupliquen los folios.

Ejemplo y Resultado esperado:

Esto es lo que me aparece cuando hago el JOIN de las dos Tablas donde la primer columna (Folio) pertenece a la primer tabla y la segunda columna (Datos) pertenece a la segunda Tabla:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>Folio</th>
   <th>Datos</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>001</td><td>Dato 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>001</td><td>Dato 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>001</td><td>Dato 3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Y lo que quiero es que aparezca lo siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>Folio</th>
   <th>Datos</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="3">001</td><td>Dato 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Dato 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Dato 3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Por favor, necesito de su ayuda, me frustra que nada me funciona. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aca no hay nada de sql, solo HTML. No sabemos como se genera ese HTML como para ayudarte. Debes poner el codigo que genera ese HTML tambien.

Comment: simplemente no se puede hacer esto en base de datos

Comment: Por lo que se esto directamente desde la db no se puede hacer. Lo que deberías de hacer seria, desde tu servidor manejar la data con condicionales if preguntando si en el `array` que tienes tu data vienen valores duplicados que solo te imprima uno y te genere cierta tabla. O bien la lógica que tu estimes conveniente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas. El problema es que mi Jefe me pide que, mediante Excel, acceda a la tabla donde se encuentran todos los datos que necesita. Ya lo he hecho desde PHP y me funciona, pero él quiere que se muestre en excel. Puesto que Excel accederá a la tabla, no logro que no se repitan los folios.

Comment: A nivel de BD no lo podrás hacer, recuerda que las consultas SQL te devuelven tuplas, cada elemento de la tubla esta asociada a un campo llamado llave primaria, lo que podrías hacer es obtener el JOIN y trabajar en tu template y darle mas o menos esa forma.

Comment: Me parece que seguiré tu consejo Fernando, tendré que hacerlo mediante una macro. Gracias por su ayuda.